# Error with Java Scanner

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner

I am brand new to Java.  I am trying to get user input.  In one part of my program this works, but using the same code in another part of my program, provides the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
at Display.displayInstructions(Display.java:31)
at SimpleWordGame.main(SimpleWordGame.java:6)
```

Here is my code for my scanner:

```
  Scanner inputChoice =  new Scanner(System.in);
  String playerChoice;
  System.out.println("Do you wish to play the Simple Word Game (Y/N)?  ");
  playerChoice = inputChoice.next();

  inputChoice.close();
```

Comment: Could be because `inputChoice.close()` closes `System.in`.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the call to

```
inputChoice.close();
```

The issue is that your scanner `Scanner inputChoice = new Scanner(System.in);` wraps the *global* `System.in`. If you `close()` it, then attempts to get input from `System.in` will fail later.

The [`Scanner.close()` JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close%28%29) says (in part)

> If this scanner has not yet been closed then if its underlying readable also implements the `Closeable` interface then the readable's close method will be invoked

and [`System.in`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in) is an [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) (and thus `Closeable`).